# How to make a image background not re-download every time you enter the page?

Tags: html, image, caching, png

I have a HTML5 site with a png image that I use in my site as a background. Every time a user goes in the site it reloads the image which takes quite a long time. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm actually your browser should take care of caching, open developer-tools and open network activities, there you can check, if the browser is caching the image or not

Comment: You should optimize the image for the web  - in photoshop or [online](http://optimizilla.com/) and you also cache it.

Comment: @doru yours worked great! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should optimize the image for the web - in gimp, photoshop, etc, or online - using [optimizilla](http://optimizilla.com/) or other image optimizers. [You also can cache it](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/),. but being an background image which doesn't change often probably this step isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 App cache. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) you got necessary information.